# Is there a reason to use a mapping of string => index into a vector, instead of string => object?

Tags: java, c++, performance, optimization, data-structures

If I have a collection of objects that I'd like to be able to look up by name, I could of course use a `{ string => object }` map.

Is there ever a reason to use a *vector* of objects along with a `{ string => index into this vector }` companion map, instead?

I've seen a number of developers do this over the years, and I've largely dismissed it as an indication that the developer is unfamiliar with maps, or is otherwise confused. But in recent days, I've started second-guessing myself, and I'm concerned I might be missing a potential optimization or something, though I can't for the life of me figure out what that could optimize.

Comment: If you have the vector first, or want to maintain its order, using the scheme you describe might be done.  It conceptually matches the concept of a database file with an index over it.

Comment: What if you need a vector of objects, but *also* need a string->object mapping? It will also allow you to change the name->object mapping very easily, or allow you to have multiple names map to the same object.

Comment: In a garbage collected world it could be safety not to keep the object alive. It could be usefull to to separate the storage of 'index' ( string+indice ) from the core data (objects)

Answer (score 6):

There is one reason I can think of:

Besides looking up object by name, sometimes you also want to iterate through all the objects as efficient as possible. Using a map + vector can achieve this. You pay a very small penalty for accessing the vector via index, but you could gain a big performance improvement by iterating a vector rather than a map (because vector is in continuous memory and more cache friendly).

Of course you can do similar thing using boost::multiindex, but that has some restrictions on the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of at least a couple reasons:

- For unrelated reasons you need to retain insertion order.
- You want to have *multiple* maps pointing into the vector (different indexes).
- Not all items in the vector need to be pointed to by a string.

Answer (score 0):

There's no optimization. If you think about it, it might actually decrease performance (albeit by a few <s>micro</s>nanoseconds). This is because the vector-based "solution" would require an extra step to find the object in the vector, while the non-vector-based solution doesn't have to do that.